# What are the rules around the clarity of safety videos? For example, how visible must screens be to each passenger, and how loudly must the video be?

Tags: inflight-entertainment

What are the rules around the clarity of safety videos, and who sets them? For example, considering airplanes without individual screens for passengers (which was common in the 90s and 00s): How far away can the screens be? What is the minimum size to ensure visibility? What volume should be set to guarantee every passenger can hear it?